# change JSON.parse functionality

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to add default parameter for `JSON.parse` to convert time format to utc after using `JSON.stringify`

```
function json_deserialize_helper(key, value) {    
    if (key === "TimeStamp") {
         value =new Date(value);
     }    return value; }

 JSON.prototype.parse = function(j,f){  f= f ||
 json_deserialize_helper;   return JSON.parse(j,f); }

 var obj = {"TimeStamp":"2016-06-09T10:37:52.000Z"} obj =
 JSON.stringify(obj); console.log(obj); obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I cannot  change in JSON.parse > how i can make that ?

Comment: You should **edit** your question to integrate it, not answer in the comments. (:

Comment: `JSON.prototype` is `undefined`. The `.prototype` object is for constructor functions.

Comment: Also, `.parse` is a method that is literally on the `JSON` object, not its prototype (prototype meaning `.__proto__`).

Comment: Formatted the code and removed unnecessary content

Comment: You shouldn't change a core functionality that way, because this could lead to problems with 3rd party libraries. If you need to use a default parameter, then then define you own function you use for json processing.

Answer (score 0):

[From the specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json-object):

> The JSON object is a single ordinary object that contains two functions, parse and stringify, that are used to parse and construct JSON texts.

This means that `JSON` is not a constructor function that would have its own prototype.

To do what you're trying to achieve, you'd have to overwrite `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse = function () { /* your logic */ }
```

However, you are probably better off just creating a completely separate function that wraps `JSON.parse` instead of replacing `JSON.parse` itself. By replacing `JSON.parse` you risk breaking any libraries that use it.